# CSS, opacity makes some fonts hides

Tags: html, css

its a big hard to explain so take a look at the code:

**HTML:**

```
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rock+Salt' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <h1>Header<span>andAnother</span></h1>
```

**CSS:**

```
h1 {
  font-family: tahoma;
  position: absolute;
}

h1 span {
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
  font-style: italic;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  left: -100px;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zp6w4dzc/), **now what is the problem?**

If you take a look at the word `and` from `andAnother` you can see that part of the `a` is missing, the reason its happen is because the `opacity` rule, if I remove the `opacity` the `a` will be shown as it should, now I almost sure that the problem is because `opacity` that is lower than `1` [creates new stacking context](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/) but I can't prove it and I'm not even sure that I'm right, if anyone can explain why and how I'll be very thankful.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zp6w4dzc/1/ insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rbga instead of opacity. i.e `color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);`

http://jsfiddle.net/zp6w4dzc/3/

Maybe it's related to this ClearType font bug... https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=494320

Editing to add [CSS opacity vs rgba: which one is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385492/css-opacity-vs-rgba-which-one-is-better)

Comment: Hi, about the bug maybe, I'm not sure, thanks for the alternative, but I'm still interesting about the reason.