# Html/Javascript Slideshow Issues in looping sequence

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I have an extremely simple javascript loop that will cycle through a preset amount of images and fade from 1 to the next continually. Here is the HTML, CSS and Javascript code:

HTML:

```
<div class="full-width-slideshow">
            <div class="large-slideshow-image" style="height:100px; width: 100%; background-color: blue;"></div>
            <div class="large-slideshow-image" style="height:100px; width: 100%; background-color: green;"></div>
            <div class="large-slideshow-image" style="height:100px; width: 100%; background-color: yellow;"></div>
            <div class="large-slideshow-image" style="height:100px; width: 100%; background-color: red;"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.large-slideshow-image {
position: absolute;
z-index:1; }
```

Javascript

```
var slideIndex = 0;
var previousSlideIndex = 4;

function carousel(){
var i = 0;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("large-slideshow-image");

for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].style.display = "none";
}
slideIndex ++;

if(slideIndex > x.length){
    slideIndex = 1;
}

x[previousSlideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
x[previousSlideIndex - 1].style.zindex = 1;
x[slideIndex - 1].style.zIndex = 5;
var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity fadein
x[slideIndex - 1].style.opacity = op
x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    if (op >= 1){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    x[slideIndex - 1].style.opacity = op;
    x[slideIndex - 1].style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op += op * 0.1;

}, 20);

previousSlideIndex = slideIndex;

setTimeout(carousel, 4000); }
```

I also have the carousel function set to trigger using onload in the body.

Everything is working fine, except for the fact that the transition from the last element to the first element of the slideshow malfunctions. Instead of the constant transition it makes between all other elements (Fade in over the last element), the last element (the red div in my case) is displayed for double the duration followed by a short flash of the next in sequence (blue div), and then moving on to the fade-in of the next element straight after (green div). It basically skips the fade-in of the first element in sequence (blue div).

One "fix" is just to remove this line of code, which results in the transitions occurring with normal timing again:

```
x[previousSlideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
```

However this results in a fade-in of the divs from the white background, while I would like them to fade in over the previous image of the slideshow.

I cannot find any reason as to why this happens, nor how to fix it. I would prefer not to use CSS for the transitions. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you can do this entire thing is CSS which would be a lot quicker and more efficient, like this: [CSS Example](https://codepen.io/eltonkamami/pen/hjBrE)

You could simply use this: [JS Example](https://codepen.io/gabrieleromanato/pen/dImly)

But yes, I've encounter this exact same problem years ago, the solution would be to put the last photo as the first photo so when it starts the loop over it won't glitch load it in which is what your getting, so just add another photo on at the end which is the same as the first one, and obviously adjust the transition timing accordingly.

```
enter code here
```

Comment: I would rather stay away from using pure CSS as I would like to be able to control the variables and possibly be able to pass them on for use with other elements. Furthermore, please correct me if I am mistaken, but I believe slightly more browser versions support RGBA than CSS transitions.

Comment: Thanks a lot though, your suggestion helped me find a solution!!! Unfortunately the duplicate image at the end of the sequence did not work, however I ended up simply changing the background of the wrapper to the image/colour of the first in sequence, then adding a line in javascript to change display to "none" once the sequence was restarted.

Comment: @Hammergold Ok cool yeah glad I could help! CSS would be best for load-times in browsers especially on mobile but yeah it does lack the ability to add things like controls on the slideshow. Yeah in some case it can be faster here is another post breaking that down --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385492/css-opacity-vs-rgba-which-one-is-better