# Webkit - Text becomes unsharp when using css transform (translate)

Tags: html, css, webkit, transform, translate-animation

I have a problem with webkit transform.

```
Without -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden
```

... many objects on my page are flickering, when i translate (like: -webkit-transform: translate(80%,0)) an object

and

```
With -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden
```

... the problem is, that child->texts become unsharp, when i move the parent (like: -webkit-transform: translate(80%,0)). It becomes sharp again, when transform->translate-value is (0,0) again.

Does somebody know a trick how i can solve this problem?

Infos: Windows, Chrome 31.0 xxx,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947385/hovering-over-css-transition-in-safari-lightens-certain-font-color). Adding the following to the element being animated should solve the problem.

```
.element {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

I've never used it so I'm unaware as to the effects it will have on page performance and compatibility, but fingers crossed, it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that you can try use `position:relative` instead with `top` or `right`. That is also sharp.