# Rotated text is breaking

Tags: css

I am trying to use [Chris Coyier's CSS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/corner-ribbon/) to put corner-ribbons on my divs..

```
.ribbon-wrapper-green {
  width: 85px;
  height: 88px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: -3px;
}

.ribbon-green {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color: #111;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0px 1px 0px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform:    rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:     rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:      rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px 0;
  left: -5px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #BFDC7A;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#BFDC7A), to(#8EBF45)); 
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #BFDC7A, #8EBF45); 
  color: #6a6340;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  box-shadow:         0px 0px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

The problem is that, when small and rotated, the text seems to break.

Here's the Fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/H6rQ6/8728/

If its not breaking in your browser, here's a snapshot of what i am facing :

[image]

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: chrome version 27.0.1453.116 m

Comment: 44 degrees seems to lessen it a bit

Comment: Strange. It looks great for me in Chrome 27.0.1453.116 mac.

Comment: Have you seen these? Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662935/text-messed-up-when-rotated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846953/wonky-text-anti-aliasing-when-rotating-with-webkit-transform-in-chrome

Comment: Thanks showdev, adding `translate3d( 0, 0, 0)` to `-webkit-transform` smoothens it completely. But it also blurs it a bit, possibly coz of the antialiasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem, thanks to showdev, by using

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
```

That's because fonts are antialiased by default in chrome, and using `translated3d(0,0,0)` smoothens them.

More here : [Wonky text anti-aliasing when rotating with webkit-transform in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846953/wonky-text-anti-aliasing-when-rotating-with-webkit-transform-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

you can try force browser to refresh/recalculate layout of text playing with font-style:
http://jsfiddle.net/H6rQ6/8730/

```
.ribbon-green {
    font-weight: bold ;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Sans-Serif;
    color: #111; 
     font-variant: small-caps;
    font-size:120%;    /* other rules */
}
```

edit, actually, it just have to do with font being too small to render smoothly.

regards

Answer (score 0):

That's completely a browser bug. You can't really avoid it.

Comment: Any documentation to back this up?

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for checking. It does sound like a browser issue with text rendering. Just strange that I don't see it in the same browser version the OP is using. I'm curious if this has been documented.

Comment: At least for me, it's zoom level dependent. If you zoom in and out, for some zoom levels it breaks in another point, or even doesn't break at all. And showing just the same in Canary, and wrong but different in FF