# CSS3 rotate animation causes blurry text

Tags: css, rotation, blur

I'm using CSS3 rotate to angle an element by 1 degree.

The effect works but unfortunately it causes the text inside to be blurry and horrible looking. Is there a way to stop the blur effect?

[Live site - click "The Makers" in nav](http://www.francesca-designed.me/smm/)

```
ul.polaroidGrid li:nth-child(even){
    transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
-moz-transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
-o-transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
-ms-transform: rotate(-1deg) ;
}

ul.polaroidGrid li:nth-child(odd) {
    transform: rotate(1deg) ;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(1deg) ;
    -moz-transform: rotate(1deg) ;
    -o-transform: rotate(1deg) ;
    -ms-transform: rotate(1deg) ;

}
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wonky text anti-aliasing when rotating with webkit-transform in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846953/wonky-text-anti-aliasing-when-rotating-with-webkit-transform-in-chrome)

Comment: To be honest, I think it looks surprisingly well, considering that fonts are always designed for display at 0deg.

Answer (score 1):

This happens in Webkit browsers such as Chrome and Safari. The fix would be to add

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 50%  51%;
```

in CSS

Comment: In my case blurry text happened only when page had scroll (if content fits the page no issue). And for the fix it worked with `-webkit-transform-origin: 50%  52%;`

LE: You may want to play a little with origin values until you find a value that fixes the issue.