# Css rotated text is jaggy

Tags: html, css

Any ideas how to get css rotated text to render properly in Chrome? In Firefox it looks acceptable.

Removing the shadow don't fix the problem and I have also tried to adjust the transition-origin without luck.

On high resolution screens it also looks just fine.

```css
 .discount-trap {
   border-bottom: 33px solid #74c331;
   border-left: 33px solid transparent;
   border-right: 33px solid transparent;
   height: 0px;
   width: 150px;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-315deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-315deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-315deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-315deg);
   transform: rotate(-315deg);
   text-align: center;
   position: absolute;
   top: 25px;
   color: white;
   text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px black;
 }
 .discount-trap__header {
   font-size: 14px;
   margin-top: 2px;
 }
 .discount-trap__text {
   font-size: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
  <div class="discount-trap" style="display: block;">
    <div class="discount-trap__header">Save 15%</div>
    <div class="discount-trap__text">Stay in Jul/Aug</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/362vtgfm/2/)

**Update:**

It looks like multiple options works, none of them make it as smooth as Firefox but that is properly a Chrome issue.
Option 1:
  Add to .discount-trap
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

Option 2:
  Add to -webkit-transform: rotate(-315deg); so it becomes -webkit-transform: rotate(-315deg) translate3d(0, 0, 0);

Comment: `body { -webkit-font-smoothing: none; }`

Comment: @Banana that don't seem to do anything either, bot in the body or directly on any of the div tags. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/362vtgfm/3/) has is on all

Comment: yea ive just googled and it seems chrome devs have removed this one. apparently they force us to use the font anti aliasing...

Comment: maybe this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6846953/wonky-text-anti-aliasing-when-rotating-with-webkit-transform-in-chrome

Comment: @Dmitriy that one helps, not as sharp as Firefox but better than nothing

Comment: @DCdaz -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; seems to do the same jo as adding translate3d(0, 0, 0);

Comment: @msr the main difference is translate3d will activate GPU acceleration.

Comment: @msr change your question title from blurry to jaggy or sharp as this is not about it being blurry it's about your font being to sharp & you require an anti aliasing fix.

Comment: @DCdaz correct. The issue with both of the solutions is before it was more clear but jagged, now it is more blurred of the anti-a.. not really great any of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome doesn't enable anti-aliasing by default. But you can add this CSS property to your elements in order to enable it:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/362vtgfm/5/)

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a transform origin `-webkit-transform-origin: 50%  50%;`

add that to `.discount-trap`

Then have a mess around with the width of `.discount-trap`

On Webkit browser's width effect's transform rendering for some reason so to de-blur it and align your letter you will need to mess with it till it render's the way you want it to.

Also set a line height to stop your letter's & number's from dancing around.

e.g. `line-height:1;`

Answer (score 1):

You add translate3d property , it will render text without blur...

```css
.discount-trap {
border-bottom: 33px solid #74c331;
  border-left: 33px solid transparent;
  border-right: 33px solid transparent;
  height: 0px;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-315deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-315deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-315deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: rotate(-315deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
  transform: rotate(-315deg) translate3d( 0, 0, 0);
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px black;
}
```