# 3D CSS transform, jagged edges in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, antialiasing, css-transforms

Similary to "[css transform, jagged edges in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492027/css-transform-jagged-edges-in-chrome)", same occurs with Firefox on 3D transforms, eg: http://jsfiddle.net/78d8K/5/ (<- remember: **Firefox**)

This time, `backface-visibility` doesn't help :(

Any idea?

Comment: Here's an updated version with Webkit support: http://jsfiddle.net/78d8K/6/

Comment: Don't care about webkit here (which is fine), it's about Firefox here :)

Comment: Vote for the bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=766345

Answer (score 157, accepted):

**Edited answer:** (after comments)

"Workaround", add a transparent ***outline*** attribute:

```
outline: 1px solid transparent;
```

Tested on Firefox 10.0.2 Windows 7: http://jsfiddle.net/nKhr8/

[image]

**Original answer:** (background-color dependent)

"Workaround", add a ***border*** attribute with the same color of your background (white this case):

```
border: 1px solid white;
```

Tested on Firefox 10.0.2 Windows 7: http://jsfiddle.net/LPEfC/

[image]

Comment: Interesting :) and actually works on the example... except when the background is no more white: http://jsfiddle.net/LPEfC/1/ I tried with `border-width:0` or `border-color:transparent` or `border-color:rgba(255,255,255,0)` in order the trick to be background-color independent — but does not work anymore... — But interesting workaround, thx!

Comment: Read my answer again, put the color "of your background" to the border

Comment: Running the example in Firefox 10.0.2 on Windows 7 laptop with screen resolution of 1366 x 768 and am still seeing the jagged edges...

Comment: As many GPU drivers allow users to manually configure aliasing behavior, I would be surprised (though, pleasantly) if you could get it looking perfect on all possible configurations.

Comment: Edit: background-color border is now a transparent outline

Comment: @Juan Mellado - nKhr8 still displays jagged on my laptop in Firefox. (note: Blender's original webkit example has no issues in google chrome on my laptop.)

Comment: @JoshuaWarner The reason this achieves "antialising" is through the presence of an invisible or white one-pixel outer border (the outline). The antialiasing comes out of texture sampling interpolation. Therefore no configuration (unless you are somehow through drivers forcing texture sample to `NEAREST` sampling) for AA (multisample etc) will affect output

Comment: Firefox 21.0 in Xubuntu did not antialiased, not working here any of the examples. :(

Comment: I didn't expect this to help anti-alias the insides of a PNG `img` that's been `rotate(15deg)` but oddly enough, it does!

Comment: Doesn't work for Mac FF when using a border-top (pointer tip). Interesting though

Comment: This did not work for my element that has `skew(10deg)`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to prevent anti-aliased border

Below worked better for me

```
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```

if the border should be clearly visible, this might not be the perfect solution though, in which you'd better stick to @Juan's answer.

Below is a taken screenshot of the cube turning

[image]

Comment: This worked on Mac Firefox for me when the accepted solution did not.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from using `outline`, the following works as well:

```
box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px transparent;
```

Answer (score -1):

`filter:blur(.25px);` works for me and doesn't looks too blurry.

Example: https://codepen.io/Grilly86/pen/QWLXBbX (try editing line 22 in the (S)CSS)