# Triangle edges in navigation appear jagged

Tags: css, navigation, geometry

I am building navigation like this: http://jsfiddle.net/techydude/XZLDq/

I had help from other members to help me figure out how to build navigation with slanted edges, however the edges do not appear smooth. Does anyone know a way to straighten out the edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with css3 skew. 
http://jsfiddle.net/XZLDq/5/

You could fix the first and last one with pseudo-elements, just like you did.

Comment: I have another question if you don't mind. The edges are smooth when they have a solid color. When I set a gradient background using this generator: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

The slants are jagged again. I updated the jsfiddle, do you see what I'm talking about? 

http://jsfiddle.net/techydude/XZLDq/7/

Comment: Found these resources. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492027/css-transform-jagged-edges-in-chrome and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235342/3d-css-transform-jagged-edges-in-firefox

I can't get them to work. But it may be because my computer doesn't support 3d transforms