# Advice on how to create this button shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

I would like to create a button that has 2 slight wings either side but not completely sure how to achieve this shape and was wondering if anyone could offer some guidance?

[image]

I understand that I will need to use the before and after psuedos but unsure how to create that slight curve going into the main body of the button?

Comment: The trapezoid is simple enough but the radiused corners will be somewhat problematical. Sometimes an image is the best way to go.

Comment: @Paulie_D how so? In my example I just used `border-top-left-radius` and `border-top-right-radius` and it was fine.

Comment: Because the angled sides will not meet the border radius at a precise point that can be described with a border-radius property. They meet at a tangent. If the button is small enough no-one will notice...but that's a design decision.

Comment: hey yeah border-radius doesn't seem to work so great with this example

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now, but only if the button is big enough to realise.

Comment: yeah the button eventually will be fluid so should be able to scale up and down without ever losing the quality

Comment: Also, your example only relates to borders. Try putting some text in the div...since this is supposed to be a button.

Comment: Text works OK (Could be better) @Paulie_D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give the impression of a 3d plane rotating away from POV, like [*Star Wars* opening crawls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_opening_crawl) (recreated [in svg too](http://codepen.io/TimPietrusky/pen/eHGfj)), use (prefixed) [perspective](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) and [rotate3d](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transforms) (or rotateX).

To prevent aliasing, use an 1px transparent outline, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333891/1654265).

<kbd>[Running example](http://jsfiddle.net/S7L2L/)</kbd>

```
#trapezoid {
    -webkit-transform : perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 20deg);
       -moz-transform : perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 20deg);
         -o-transform : perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 20deg);
        -ms-transform : perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 20deg);
            transform : perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 20deg);

        border-radius : 5px 5px 0 0;
              outline : 1px solid transparent;
}
```

If you instead do not want the text to be rotated, apply the code above to the `::before` pseudo element, absolutely positioned relatively to its parent:

<kbd>[Running example with non rotated text](http://jsfiddle.net/S7L2L/3/)</kbd>

Code:

```
#trapezoid {    
         width : 200px;
        height : 50px;
        margin : 10px;
       padding : 10px;
      position : relative;
    text-align : center;
}

#trapezoid::before {
    -webkit-transform : perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 20deg);
       -moz-transform : perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 20deg);
         -o-transform : perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 20deg);
        -ms-transform : perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 20deg);
            transform : perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 20deg);
              outline : 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius : 5px 5px 0 0;
             position : absolute;
                  top : 0;
               bottom : 0;
                 left : 0;
                right : 0;
              content : '';
              z-index : -1;
           background : red;
}
```

Comment: You'd probably have to include some compatibility `.js` to make this work on `<= IE9`

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [this site here.](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

You can create thate shape by using this:

```
#trapezoid {
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

[Here is an example](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/xLcCG)

If you want text, put text in the div and add to the css this:

```
text-align:center;
line-height:30px; /*Size of bottom border*/
```

However you'll need to do some fiddling to get it to the right width and height etc.

UPDATED EXAMPLE

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that style by using `:before` and `:after`. The trick is to skew the elements on the sides and apply a little border-radius for the smooth rounding, like this:

```
button {
  border: 0 none;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;

  font-size: 4em;
  margin-left: 100px; 
}

button:before,
button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: inherit;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 1em;
  z-index: -1;
}

button:before {
  left: -0.5em;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg);
  transform: skew(-10deg);
  border-top-left-radius: 10%;
}

button:after {
  left: auto;
  right: -0.5em;
  -webkit-transform: skew(10deg);
  transform: skew(10deg);
  border-top-right-radius: 10%;
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JyhwZ/1/

Comment: Works well except in IE.

Comment: It's nice but I think you have a lot of magic numbers in there....I'd be interested to see how flexible it is at smaller sizes, different widths etc. Still...nice!

Comment: It should be pretty flexible since I used `ems` and `%`. In the fiddle, just change the font-size of the button from 4em to anything to see the button adapting. The only px-based value is the margin-left of the button which I use to only make enough space on the left side of the button for the :before to be fully visble.

Answer (score 1):

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/OPiBIGI/1/edit)

[image]

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
```

```
ul{
  list-style:none;
  border-bottom:2px solid #000;
  overflow:auto;
}
ul li a{
  color:#fff;
  float:left;
  border-bottom: 30px solid #EC2327;
  border-left:   4px solid transparent;
  border-right:  4px solid transparent;
  border-top:    4px solid #EC2327;
  border-radius: 14px 14px 0 0;
  height: 0;
  padding:0 20px;
  line-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
}
a.active{
  border-bottom-color: #000;
  border-top-color:    #000;
}
```