# Border circle looks blurry

Tags: css, border, css-shapes

This circle with border looks blurry. Is it possible to fix it and how?

```css
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: @ctabuyo - What are you talking about?

Comment: All browsers. no, i want it 1px solid. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: can you use an image?

Comment: AFAIK, what you're seeing is a result of anti-aliasing at a certain pixel resolution. You can fix it with a better screen (obviously not what you wanted), or (depending on your actual use case) use an image instead.

Answer (score 8):

Using **box-shadow** with a transparent border seems to make it less blurry too with chrome.
In the following example, the first circle is the original and the second is made with a box-shadow  :

```css
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  background-color: white;
  float:left;
}
div + div{
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  border-color:transparent;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px #000;
  margin:1px 3px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `transform: rotate(45deg)` helps, but not `transform: translateZ(1px) rotate(45deg)`:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div + div {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

div + div + div {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateZ(1px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div></div> <div></div> <div></div>
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20957574/4928642).

Answer (score 1):

Using Two divs has a better render effect.

```css
div, svg {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
p {
  float :left;
}

#div0{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#div1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
}

#div2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 22px;
  width: 22px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div0"></div>
<p>Original</p>

<svg width=26 height=26>
  <circle cx=13 cy=13 r=12 stroke-width=1 stroke=black fill=none />
</svg>
<p>SVG</p>

<div id="div1">
  <div id="div2">
  </div>
</div>
<p>Nested</p>
```

Comment: doesn't seem like a significant difference from the original.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't.

Comment: Put both methods side by side for comparison, and fixed off-by-one width/height

Comment: Nested at 110% are... strange :D

Comment: @Qwertiy yeah -- getting that too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using svg and make a circle a little bigger:

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<svg width=56 height=26>
  <circle cx=13 cy=13 r=12 stroke-width=1 stroke=black fill=none />
  <circle cx=43 cy=13 r=11.5 stroke-width=1 stroke=black fill=none />
</svg>

<div></div>
```

Comment: Added to the answer below for comparison...not trying to steal your answer :)