# CSS3 transform rotate causes jagged edges in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, rotation, transform

I am using `transform perspective(550px) rotateY(40deg)` on button hover and it works just fine on every single browser except for Firefox. I've already tried using `border: 1px solid transparent` or `outline: 1px solid transparent` with no visible effect. I have tested this on Windows 7 and 8, as well as on Ubuntu 12.04. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: problem]

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle example of your problem?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235342/3d-css-transform-jagged-edges-in-firefox

Comment: It does, doesn't it? The thing is using outline and/or border did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: The difference between this situation and the other one is that I am using a rotate with perspective, instead of a transform3D.