# CSS Transform Perspective bad pixelation in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, transform, pixel

I am trying to make tabs like Chrome tabs. I use:

```
transform:perspective(4px) rotateX(-1deg);
-webkit-transform:perspective(4px) rotateX(-1deg);
-moz-transform:perspective(4px) rotateX(-1deg);
```

It looks nice in Chrome and IE, but in FF the left border is pixelated;

Firefox
[image: Firefox]

Chrome/IE
[image: Chrome/IE]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Huh, that's unusual historically FF has handled things like this better than chrome [as in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492027/css-transform-jagged-edges-in-chrome) not sure if you could try the backface visibility with a `-moz` prefix?

Answer (score 3):

Issue was solved with

```
outline: 1px solid transparent;
```

[3D CSS transform, jagged edges in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235342/3d-css-transform-jagged-edges-in-firefox)