# Triangle shaped pointer / border on a horizontal line

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am trying to create triangle shaped pointer/border on a horizontal line.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Example]

I tried manipulating the top border of a div, but everything I've done so far doesn't work at all.

Comment: Tutorial on triangles via css: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve that and it probably depends on your layout. One solution is to use a rotated element with borders on two sides.

```
.triangle {
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```css
.box {
  background: green;
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  height: 39px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
}

.triangle {
  background: green;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-width: 2px 2px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: 28px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="line">
    <div class="triangle">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements:

```css
body{
    background:black;
}
div{
    border-top:1px solid green;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

div:before{
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    left: calc(90% - 20px);
    top: -9px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent black transparent;
    z-index: 10;
}

div:after{
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    right:10%;
    top: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 10px 10px 10px;
    border-color: transparent transparent green transparent;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Basiclly, there are two triangles, one is in the color of the background with larger `z-index`, and the other one is in the color of the border.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/stjkwyf2/1)

**Update**

As [@misterManSam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2930477/mistermansam) mentioned, you can achieve it without using `z-index` - [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/jihojo/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: This solution is also great. If I only can accept two answers
Thank you very much!

Comment: +1 for no extra, unnecessary markup. Keep the styling elements in the CSS like this answer does @AlexanderLomov :)

Comment: @Vucko - [Here is an alternative](http://jsbin.com/jihojo/1/edit?html,css,output) I made based on your answer. It more closely resembles the picture in the question and doesn't include calc() which is not really needed :) though it does rely on a transform. The z-index should not be needed at all.

Comment: @misterManSam your solution is also good, there's no need for adding extra markup :)

Comment: @Vucko - I made it from your example, just tweaked it, so feel free to add it as an additional snippet in your answer so it doesn't get lost in the comments :)

Comment: @misterManSam I've updated my answer with you fiddle :)

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a single div element.

Here's a quick demo:

```css
html,body{background:green; height:100%;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden;}
.line {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.line:after,
.line:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}
.line:after {
  left: calc(100% + 2px);
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  top: -13px;
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  border-left: 5px solid #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.line:before {
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: calc(100% + 34px);
  width: 20%;
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: what's wrong with the gray color between the borders

Comment: @sdx11 what browser are you using? Can't replicate

Comment: here is screenshot https://imgur.com/a/vzjBx firefox only when applying the css transform:rotate(45deg)

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333891/3436942)

Comment: many thanks for the example, I found the solution it was the background-clip attribute when I set it to content-box the issue was gone https://imgur.com/a/VzT6o

Comment: Glad to hear you got sorted.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
}

.box .line {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  height: 2px;
  background: white;
}

.box .triangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 8px solid white;
  border-left: 8px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid transparent;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.box .triangle .inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: -6px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-bottom: 6px solid green;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="triangle"><div class="inner"></div></div>
</div>
```