# Firefox renders poorly box shadow when rotation applied

Tags: css, firefox

I have an issue with Firefox rendering element to which is applied box shadow and rotation.
Is there any fix for this? I tried to apply rotateZ() backface visibility, no results.

```css
.button{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out 0s;
    background: #FFB600;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0px #DC6900, 0.2em 0.2em 1px #A32020;
    transform:rotate(3deg);
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 1.5em;
    background-color: #DC6900;
}
```

```html
<a class="button">I am fancy button</a>
```

Firefox rendering [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTPYt.png)

Comment: I don't really see a difference between Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Oh, maybe it is working in Windows, I`ll check, definitely an issue on OSX

Answer (score 0):

Just can add a border:

```
border: 1px solid #DC6900;
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9333891/1064270

```css
.button{
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    line-height: 5.5em;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out 0s;
    background: #FFB600;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    box-shadow: 0.1em 0.1em 0px #DC6900, 0.2em 0.2em 1px #A32020;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    transform:rotate(3deg);
    padding-right: 1.5em;
    background-color: #DC6900;
}

.with-border{border: 1px solid #DC6900;}
```

```html
<a class="button">I am fancy button</a> 
<br/>
<br/>
<a class="button with-border">I have a border</a>
```

Comment: I am still seeing the issue OP was talking about, with that CSS.

Comment: yes, yet it is a little better. See the difference in the snippet