# Div's border isn't a straight line after rotating in Firefox in Mac

Tags: javascript, html, macos, css

I have a div which has two child div's, one div on the screen plan and other vertically perpendicular to the screen.

I try to rotate the div along `Y axis` for about `30 degrees`. keeping its `transform-style 3d preserved`.

When doing it, in Firefox the border isn't a straight line anymore. It looks like this

[image: This is the whole div]

For closer view

[image: Closer view]

I happen to use the following code

```css
.holder {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 226px;
  perspective: 2000px;
  -moz-perspective: 2000px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 226px;
  background-color: transparent;

  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(30deg);
  -moz-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(30deg);

  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.box div {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
 }

.box .front {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(10px);
    -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(10px);

    background-color: grey;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.box .left {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 20px;

    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(10px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(10px);

    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Picture of the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jeus8boz/1/) provided in one of the answers : [image]

Comment: Hope you've searched before posting it as a question as here already available one. [**Please look into this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235342/3d-css-transform-jagged-edges-in-firefox) this would help you, as most of already posted it as an answer, LoL ;)

Comment: Good find @vivekkupadhyay. As this is a well known problem, I didn't bother searching for an existing question. I am marking this as a dupe right away.

Comment: I found the question, yet the answers provided doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Can you have a look at this problem once again, as the answers provided in your link isn't working either.

Comment: @Presse your given link in the que is working perfectly fine on my end, which browser version are you using ?

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Firefox version 40.0.3 and OS - OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.4

Comment: @Presse I've checked on 41.0(normal) and 42.0(Developer Edition) and its working fine, windows 8.1

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay Is there any other possible workarounds that I could try?

Comment: @Presse it looks good (no pixel steps) in firefox 40.0.3 and windows 7

Comment: @LucianDepold Even I checked in windows. It seems like the problem is appearing with Ubuntu and Mac systems.

Comment: did you test on those systems directly or did you use something that simulates them ? maybe the simulation causes the trouble. You should add the linux aspect to your question.

Comment: No I'm using the system directly. No Emulators. Sure will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a work around for your issue [reference](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2014/05/04/fixing-typography-inside-of-2-d-css-transforms/).

Try `filter` for the div having `class="box"`.

Basically this is used for `svg` elements but it is working for your case as well.

```
filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><filter id="gaussian_blur"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0" /></filter></defs></svg>#gaussian_blur');
```

Tested in latest version of Opera, FF and Chrome for both mac and windows.

[Working Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jeus8boz/8/)

Answer (score 4):

It's a Firefox aliasing problem, you can add

```
outline: 1px solid transparent;
```

as a workaround to `.box .front`.

Comment: I just clicked the fiddle you posted, it still looks the same. I'll update the picture in the question for your reference

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why using `translateZ` inside a transformed element is not works properly on FF.

Adding `outline: 1px solid transparent;` is not working, but adding `border: 1px solid transparent;` to the `.box` will working, with removing `transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(10px);` from the `.box .front`.

**Example:**

```css
.holder {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 226px;
  perspective: 2000px;
  -moz-perspective: 2000px;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 226px;
  background-color: transparent;

  border: 1px solid transparent;

  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;

  transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(30deg);
  -moz-transform: translateZ( -100px ) rotateY(30deg);

  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.box div {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
 }

.box .front {
    left: 0;
    right: -4px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    /* transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(10px); */
    /* -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(10px); */

    background-color: grey;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.box .left {
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 20px;

    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(10px);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(10px);

    background-color: black;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```