# CSS transform: skew, jagged edges

Tags: css

Similary to [css transform, jagged edges in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6492027/css-transform-jagged-edges-in-chrome) and [3D CSS transform, jagged edges in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235342/3d-css-transform-jagged-edges-in-firefox).

I've searched a lot of article for this problem, I use `transform: skew`.

I tried to use `backface-visibility: hidden` and `outline: 1px solid transparent`, but it donesn't work :(

Here is my code: https://codepen.io/evenloooo/pen/BOjRBx

There is a jagged edges screentshot on Chrome 68.0.3440.106 and Microsoft Edge:

[image]

I hope the central line is smooth, no jagged edges.

Any idea?

Comment: what will be your final output? the desired result?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I hope the central line is smooth, no jagged edges.

Comment: I know, I mean where you will use this, what will be the layout .. I am sure you will not have web page with only that skewed element? and depending on your situation, we may find workarounds