# CSS 'transform rotate' creates artifacts

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

I've done this in CSS.

[image: image 2]

It works great in Google Chrome after adding:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
```

But in FireFox it looks like this:

[image: image 3]

See [source here](http://jsbin.com/pedudogejo/1/edit?html,css,output)

I tried several things and searched a lot. I don't know what to do to get rid of those borders FireFox creates. Most stuff I find is about transition, which I don't use. Any ideas would be very much welcome.

References:
- [CSS3 transform rotate causing 1px shift in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729492/css3-transform-rotate-causing-1px-shift-in-chrome)
- [-webkit-transform rotate - Pixelated images in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078186/webkit-transform-rotate-pixelated-images-in-chrome)
- [CSS transition effect makes image blurry / moves image 1px, in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome)

Comment: mh, in Firefox I get a blank page..

Comment: @Andreas maybe the image doesn't work? That's weird. Could you try this one? http://jsbin.com/pedudogejo/1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding `translateZ(1px)` before the rotation rule seems to remove those artifacts:

```
transform: translateZ(1px) rotate(-45deg);
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406355/anti-aliasing-on-rotated-div-with-border-image-in-firefox).

Comment: Hey Andreas, thanks for your help. It works great in Chrome, Firefox and Safari but I just found out that the bug still occurs in IE & Edge. If you have any idea it'd be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Kev - I fixed this in IE by adding `background-clip: padding-box;` to the rotated element.